# Cannot run program "phantomjs": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, android, phantomjs

I am trying to launch a simple.js by using PhantomJS. I am doing this to retrieve some JS generated content inside of my android app. However, when I used

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("phantomjs simple.js");
```

I got an error:

> Cannot run program "phantomjs": error=13, Permission denied.

What should I change? This is the only line of code I really use and try to change. Other lines don't affect, or still are unreachable.

Thank you, 
Dmitry

Comment: looks like you need root

Comment: What are the permissions on that file? Note that I've never heard of running phantomjs on an Android platform and would be surprised if it worked.

Comment: @DmitryKustarnikov You could try running npm cache clean (in the case that you are using node/npm for your app) Error 13 is usually a permissions error [ sometimes caused by antivirus software blocking access].  Clearing the cache is worth a shot